# video stream in chrome makes my laptop fry

Tags: google-chrome, video, overheating, gpu-driver

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 having **intel i7-8565U CPU** and **geforce MX150 GPU**. I use [gotomeeting](https://www.gotomeeting.com/) for my online lectures and the problem is gotomeeting has not developed application for linux distros so I run the lectures in chrome.

After some time my laptop becomes so hot that sometimes I cannot even touch it. My cpu throttles around **80 - 100 deg C** and when I checked my cpu info i saw frequency was around **2.5 - 3GHz**

and Gotomeetings has only support for chrome

maybe gpu report can help

```
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
OpenGL: Enabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Unavailable
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Unavailable
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Hardware accelerated
WebGL2: Hardware accelerated


Driver Bug Workarounds
adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
disable_discard_framebuffer
exit_on_context_lost
force_cube_complete
init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
init_vertex_attributes
pack_parameters_workaround_with_pack_buffer
reset_base_mipmap_level_before_texstorage
scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
unpack_alignment_workaround_with_unpack_buffer
unpack_overlapping_rows_separately_unpack_buffer
use_virtualized_gl_contexts
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
disabled_extension_GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
disabled_extension_GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y


Problems Detected
Accelerated video decode is unavailable on Linux: 137247, 1032907
Disabled Features: accelerated_video_decode
Protected video decoding with swap chain is for Windows and Intel only
Disabled Features: protected_video_decode
Program link fails in NVIDIA Linux if gl_Position is not set: 286468
Applied Workarounds: init_gl_position_in_vertex_shader
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Linux NVIDIA drivers don't have the correct defaults for vertex attributes: 351528
Applied Workarounds: init_vertex_attributes
Always rewrite vec/mat constructors to be consistent: 398694
Applied Workarounds: scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
MakeCurrent is slow on Linux with NVIDIA drivers: 449150, 514510
Applied Workarounds: use_virtualized_gl_contexts
NVIDIA fails glReadPixels from incomplete cube map texture: 518889
Applied Workarounds: force_cube_complete
Pack parameters work incorrectly with pack buffer bound: 563714
Applied Workarounds: pack_parameters_workaround_with_pack_buffer
Alignment works incorrectly with unpack buffer bound: 563714
Applied Workarounds: unpack_alignment_workaround_with_unpack_buffer
Framebuffer discarding can hurt performance on non-tilers: 570897
Applied Workarounds: disable_discard_framebuffer
Unpacking overlapping rows from unpack buffers is unstable on NVIDIA GL driver: 596774
Applied Workarounds: unpack_overlapping_rows_separately_unpack_buffer
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
glTexStorage* are buggy when base mipmap level is not 0: 877874
Applied Workarounds: reset_base_mipmap_level_before_texstorage
Some drivers can't recover after OUT_OF_MEM and context lost: 893177
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
adjust src/dst region if blitting pixels outside framebuffer on Linux NVIDIA: 830046
Applied Workarounds: adjust_src_dst_region_for_blitframebuffer
Disable GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y for desktop GL: 964010
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y)
```

any suggestion would be very helpfull. Thanks

Comment: Is your Chrome browser set to use "hardware acceleration"? Open Chrome's settings, type 'hardware' into the search bar, and the option should appear. If it's on, turn it off. If it's off, leave it off and move to the next troubleshooting step. You'll need to restart the browser after disabling it.

Comment: yes, Use hardware acceleration when available is turned on

Comment: Turn it off and restart Chrome. Chrome's HA doesn't *really* work with Linux, so you're not losing out on anything by turning it off. So, check to see if that resolves the problem. You will want to let the laptop cool off, dissipate some heat, before testing it - if you are currently running hot. A few minutes should do the trick.

Comment: I also tried tested after tirning it off for a long time i dont think this will affect anything because if HA is not available then it simply wouldn't work.

Comment: No, that's not quite right. If it's enabled, it can cause all sorts of weird bugs. This site is full of such instances. Sadly, if it doesn't work it doesn't just sit there toggled on. It's so common that it's the first step I suggest in troubleshooting browser and video issues. In this case, that's seemingly not the problem. So, the next step would be checking fan speeds when the computer is under load.

Comment: my fan speed is also proper it dynamically increases at full speed when temprature increases. And other than that my system works fine and also get less hot while playing eg. youtube videos

Comment: This is a weird one. I'll keep looking and throw a vote at your question to get more eyes on it. In the meantime, searching says [Firefox is an option](https://www.gotomeeting.com/features/mac-windows-linux). So, I'd try other browsers - as they indicate that's an option. There's also the option of installing Windows in a VM, because you *really* don't want heat degrading your computer.

Comment: No the vm wont work because all my stuff is in this OS and i won't able to present the screen. Oh i thought it won't work in Firefox maybe that will solve my issue. Btw thanks for your help

Comment: Yes i was right it doesn't work properly in Firefox as various problems occurs like this https://amp.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/benolg/gotomeeting_doesnt_work_in_firefox_the_developers/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111417/discussion-between-kgiii-and-techno-world).